# Pass form data to parent class in react

Tags: reactjs

I have following react classes:

```
var FormBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>Forms:</h1>
            <InternalForm name="foo" />
            <InternalForm name="bar" />
            <form className="externalForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="submit" value="Post" /> 
            </form>
        );
  }
})
var InternalForm = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
            <form className="internalForm">
                <input type="text"/>
                /* form strucure based on props*/
            </form>
    );
  }
})
```

After external form submition, I need to get a json that contains values of intertal forms like

```
{'foo':{},'bar':{}}
```

I guess that FormBox needs to call onSubmit on each internal form, but it doesn't feel quite right.

How to perform it?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need a <form> element in the internal form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, calling onSubmit on each Subcomponent is not the way you would do this in react. Instead of this, you should hold a state object in your external containing the values of foo and bar. To keep them in sync, you should pass a callback to the child forms so they update the state when needed. Then when submitting you only need to use the external form's state.

Something like this:

```js
var FormBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        foo: null,
        var: null
      };  
    },
  
    onChildChange: function(childName, childValue){
      let newState = {};
      newState[childName] = childValue;
      this.setState(newState)
    },
  
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>Forms:</h1>
            <InternalForm name="foo" onFormChange={this.onChildChange}/>
            <InternalForm name="bar" onFormChange={this.onChildChange} />
            <form className="externalForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.onChildChange.bind(this, 'bar')}>
                <input type="submit" value="Post" /> 
            </form>
        );
  }
})
var InternalForm = React.createClass({
    onFormChange: function(e) {
        this.props.onFormChange(this.props.name, e.target.value);
    }
  
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
            <form className="internalForm">
                <input type="text" onChange={this.onFormChange}/>
                /* form strucure based on props*/
            </form>
    );
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any source (guide, article) for this ?

Comment: You can check this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html